# Javascript Fill array with missing object and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like bellow each index contains different set of objects,I want to  create an uniformal data where object missing in each index will with Value:0 ,

```
var d = [
          [
            {axis:"Email",value:59,id:1},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:56,id:2},

          ],
          [

            {axis:"Sending Money",value:18,id:6},
            {axis:"Other",value:15,id:7},

          ]
        ];
```

how can I get an array like bellow using above above array

```
var d = [
          [
            {axis:"Email",value:59,id:1},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:56,id:2},
            {axis:"Sending Money",value:0,id:6},
            {axis:"Other",value:0,id:7},

          ],
          [
            {axis:"Email",value:0,id:1},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:0,id:2},
            {axis:"Sending Money",value:18,id:6},
            {axis:"Other",value:15,id:7},

          ]
        ];
```

Comment: And what is your question about that?

Comment: By iterating over it.

Comment: is It possible to do this? if yes ,how ?is there any function to manipulate array ?

Comment: @matrixwebtech Native JS methods are all you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array Also, people on SO generally don't like answering questions where the person asking has demonstrated no interest in attempting to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Does the order in the arrays matter? Why  is `Email` the first and not `Sending Money`? Is the list of names fixed or do you want to compute it from the data you have? If you can provide the list, e.g. `var headers = ['Email', 'Social Networks', 'Sending Money', 'Other']` then it is easy to generate the output, even with the desired order. If you cannot, then it's still easy to generate the missing entries, but the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two functions:

*getAllEntries* that find all objects and stores them into a variable *accEntries*. Then *accEntries* is used to search for all occurrences in a sub-array of *d*. This whole process is done in *checkArray*.

*checkArray* is used to fetch all found and not-found entries in *d*. Both Arrays (found and not-found) are then used to build a new sub-array that contains either found entries with certain values and/or not-found entries with values of 0.

Hope this helps:

```js
var d = [
  [
  {
    axis: 'Email',
    value: 59,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    axis: 'Social Networks',
    value: 56,
    id: 2
  },
  ],
  [
    {
      axis: 'Sending Money',
      value: 18,
      id: 6
    },
    {
      axis: 'Other',
      value: 15,
      id: 7
    },
  ]
];
  

function getAllEntries(array) {
  var uniqueEntries = [];
  array.forEach(function (subarray) {
    subarray.forEach(function (obj) {
      if (uniqueEntries.indexOf(obj) === - 1) uniqueEntries.push(obj);
    });
  });
  return uniqueEntries;
}


function checkArray(array, acceptedEntries) {
  var result = [];
  array.forEach(function (subArray) {
    var subResult = [];
    var foundEntries = [];
    subArray.forEach(function (obj) {
      if (foundEntries.indexOf(obj.axis) === - 1) foundEntries.push(obj.axis);
    });
    var notFound = acceptedEntries.filter(function (accepted) {
      return foundEntries.indexOf(accepted.axis) === - 1;
    });
    foundEntries.forEach(function (found) {
      subArray.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj.axis === found) subResult.push(obj);
      });
    });
    notFound.forEach(function (notfound, index) {
      subResult.push({
        axis: notfound.axis,
        value: 0,
        id: notfound.id
      });
    });
    result.push(subResult);
  });
  return result;
}


var accEntries = getAllEntries(d);
var result = checkArray(d, accEntries);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: At least, you can view the desired array when you press "run code snippet". Description is still comming

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array to find all the unique objects and then again loop over to push the values that are not present comparing with the array of objects of unique keys.

You can use ES6 syntax to find if an object with an attribute is present like `uniKeys.findIndex(obj => obj.axis === val.axis);` and the to push with a zero value use the spread syntax like `d[index].push({...val, value: 0});`

Below is the snippet for the implementation

```js
var d = [
          [
            {axis:"Email",value:59,id:1},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:56,id:2},

          ],
          [

            {axis:"Sending Money",value:18,id:6},
            {axis:"Other",value:15,id:7},
            {axis:"Social Networks",value:89,id:2},
          ]
        ];
            
var uniKeys = [];
  $.each(d, function(index, item) {
  
              $.each(item, function(idx, val){
                    const pos = uniKeys.findIndex(obj => obj.axis === val.axis);
               
               if(pos == - 1) {
                    uniKeys.push(val);
                }
                
               })
            })
  
  $.each(d, function(index, item) {
             var temp = [];
              $.each(uniKeys, function(idx, val){
                    const pos = item.findIndex(obj => obj.axis === val.axis);
               
               if(pos == - 1) {
                    
                    d[index].push({...val, value: 0});
                    
                }
                
               })
              
            })
  console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please, do not take me wrong but is Social Networks within the second sub-array correct? Or do I have tomatos on my eyes.

Comment: @Blauharley, I suppose it is correct according to my implemetation. For demostration, I have added an extra object in the original array just to give a case when the object is present in both arrays, Have a look at my input first

Answer (score -1):

How about a short `shallowCopy` function (`Object.assign` is not available in IE) and otherwise less than 10 new lines of code?

```
var d = [
      [
        {axis:"Email",value:59,id:1},
        {axis:"Social Networks",value:56,id:2}
      ],
      [
        {axis:"Sending Money",value:18,id:6},
        {axis:"Other",value:15,id:7}
      ]
    ];

var newD_0 = [shallowCopy(d[0][0]), shallowCopy(d[0][1]), shallowCopy(d[1][0]), shallowCopy(d[1][1])];
var newD_1 = [shallowCopy(d[0][0]), shallowCopy(d[0][1]), shallowCopy(d[1][0]), shallowCopy(d[1][1])];

newD_0[2].id = 0; 
newD_0[3].id = 0;
newD_1[0].id = 0;
newD_1[1].id = 0;

d = [newD_0, newD_1];

function shallowCopy(obj) {
    var copy = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            copy[key] = obj[key];   
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
```

RESULT:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "axis":"Email",
         "value":59,
         "id":1
      },
      {  
         "axis":"Social Networks",
         "value":56,
         "id":2
      },
      {  
         "axis":"Sending Money",
         "value":18,
         "id":0
      },
      {  
         "axis":"Other",
         "value":15,
         "id":0
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "axis":"Email",
         "value":59,
         "id":0
      },
      {  
         "axis":"Social Networks",
         "value":56,
         "id":0
      },
      {  
         "axis":"Sending Money",
         "value":18,
         "id":6
      },
      {  
         "axis":"Other",
         "value":15,
         "id":7
      }
   ]
]
```